# Modifying a CE transistor Amp to a Single Ended Class B Amp

Tags: transistors, ac, common-emitter

I've designed the above amplifier to give an Av=10 and be mid point bias. I simulated it and it's all working well. But I need to modify the bias (so only changing resistor values, not adding or removing components) in order for Vout to look like a Class B amplifier. By this I mean the output should only change with input for half the ac signal.

I think I should move the Q point on the DC load line to either Ic=Ic(sat) or Vce=Vcc to only allow half the AC signal to be outputted, but I don't understand how to mathematically choose the resistors needed to do this. Any help would be appreciated. Only set conditions are Vcc=10, use all 4 resistors, use BC107 (no additional transistors) and have a Class B output.

Please note I'll be doing the same with class Ab and C afterwards, so I'm more interested in methods or techniques than just values

[image: schematic]

Comment: This is a common-emitter configuration. Usually, class B is obtained with two BJTs, to amplify both positive and negative wave halves, and each BJT works in common-collector (aka emitter follower) configuration.

Comment: See above comment, this circuit always works as a "Class A" amplifier however you bias it. Class B means that one of the output transistors is off while there's still a varying output signal, this circuit cannot do that.

Comment: And Alessio thanks for the reply man, when you put both the transistors together you get a circuit that is active when input is + or - right? So at any time only one transistor is active, but the output across the circuit is the full wave. What Im looking to do is just one transistor that only does one half of the input. I don't need the other half of the input signal to be used at all, could this be achieved by one BJT in common collector? (New to these amplifiers and only worked with CE so far but I'll happily read up if it's relevant!)

Comment: Why don't you just use a diode to block the negative half cycle.

Comment: The problem specifically said without adding or removing components. This isn't a real life problem, it's an educational one from a uni paper! But yeah that's how I'd do it in real life science geyser!

Comment: If you are amplifying a narrow-band signal, say like a 1MHz AM signal with a 10 kHz bandwidth, then you can bias a transistor so that it only turns on for part of the input wave. The transistor then makes pulses. This seems useless, except ( because of the narrow band stuff), you can put a resonant circuit around the transistor, and the pulses get turned into sine waves, bigger than the input. This is how single transistor class B amplifiers work in a practical application.

Answer (score 1):

> I think I should move the Q point on the DC load line to either Ic=Ic(sat) or Vce=Vcc to only allow half the AC signal to be outputted,

This answer involves setting the Q point to Ic=Ic(sat) rather than I(cutoff). Although it amplifies half the AC signal, in common emitter configuration, it does not have the nice quality of low quiescent power found in "real" class B amplifiers.

To amplify only a half-cycle of an input wave, you may set the Q-point of your amplifier on the saturation line of your transistor. "A" is an example of point on the saturation line. This may or may not qualify as a class-B amplifier, but it will give you a half-cycle output (but with a twist -- it is inverted).

[image: Image taken from https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-switching-characteristics-of-BJT]
[Image taken from [Quara.com](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-switching-characteristics-of-BJT)]

Although the diagram does not show it, in general, there will be multiple values of \$I_{B}\$ that will have characteristics that pass through that point. Choose the *lowest* value of \$I_B\$ that has a characteristic that passes through that point.

If your Q-point is set as described, if the input should raise the voltage at the base of your transistor, there will be no increase in \$I_C\$ and therefore no increase in \$V_{R2}\$, and hence no change in \$V_{out}\$. However, if the input should decrease the base voltage, there will be a decrease in \$I_C\$, and a corresponding drop in \$V_{R2}\$, and a rise in \$V_{out}\$.

Thus, because this is an inverting amplifier, "negative" half cycles on the base will cause positive half cycles on the output.

Here is an example circuit (not using your transistor, however):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNzXCB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The waveform generated by this circuit looks like this:
[image]

A significant disadvantage of this design is that when the input is quiescent, the transistor is "on". The opposite design is to set the Q-point of the amplifier at cutoff. The advantage of that design is that when the input is quiescent, the transistor is "off". A disadvantage is, that for an inverting amplifier, the quiescent voltage will be high (if taken from the collector to ground), and will drop when an input is applied.

Answer (score 0):

Change the values of R1 and/or R4 so that the transistor is not quite turned on, ie. the voltage on the Base should be a bit less than 0.6 V (eg. change R1 to 330k and you should get ~0.5 V). The transistor should then be turned off when 'quiescent', and positive halves of the AC signal should turn it on.

Answer (score 0):

If you adjust the bias circuit to just about or few mV above the voltage over a base-emitter junction. I.e. 0.6V where the transistor is close to off, then voltages above that will turn the transistor on whereas negative voltage will not get amplified because the transistor is already off.

Simulating different scenarios reveals that this is far from ideal:
[image]

Blue is the collector voltage offset by the supply voltage to get a good plot.
Green is the base voltage.

As series of 6 different bias voltages are selected. If bias is too high above 0.6V it works like a class A (lower blue, upper green). If too low, some of the signal amplitude is lost (upper blue, lower green).

As you see, some compromise must be taken.
Moreover the circuit will be sensitive to the temperature because this affects the Vbe.

[image]
Simulated with [LTSpice](https://www.analog.com/en/design-center/design-tools-and-calculators/ltspice-simulator.html)